# Do Dockerfile WORKDIR, ENTRYPOINT, VOLUME ... apply to child images?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to create two Docker images, one being the child of the other. But I don't know if the properties (such as **WORKDIR**, **ENTRYPOINT** , **VOLUME**, ...) I specified in the parent will apply to child.

For example if I have these two images with these two Dockerfiles :

- ***myrepo/webapp-build***

  ```
  FROM ruby:2.2.3

  RUN mkdir -p /app
  WORKDIR /app

  COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
  RUN gem install bundler && bundle install

  VOLUME /app
  ENTRYPOINT ["bundle", "exec"]
  ```
- ***myrepo/webapp***

  ```
  FROM myrepo/webapp-build

  COPY . ./

  EXPOSE 3000

  CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
  ```

Will the second image copy the files into */app* ? Will my entrypoint in the second image be *bundle exec* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those properties do propagate from one base image to another using said base image (with a [`FROM` directive](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from)).

But regarding `WORKDIR`, it is better to repeat it in order to document what '.' means in a `COPY . xxx`